# Unable to get an object from a map giving d/t result for hardcoded value and dynamic value but having equal value

Tags: groovy

I dont know how to describe the problem, so weird. I have function like this:

```
long getPersonId(...){
//...
}
```

The above function returns Id of a person based on some arguments.

So I logged the return value of the function and it is `1`.

Then I have code like this:

```
person = myMap.get(getPersonId(..))
```

which returns null object but this returns a valid Person object, why?:

```
person = myMap.get(1)
```

But as I described before `getPersonId(..)` returns `1`, which basically means

```
myMap.get(getPersonId(..)) == myMap.get(1)
```

`myMap` is typed as `Map<Long, Person> myMap`

What is happening here?

Comment: how do you debug this behaviour?  could as well be, that your method there returns something, that prints/toStrings to "1".

Comment: hmm also have you tried returning a Long (no long) out of desperation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Groovy, as in Java, `1` is an *int* literal, not a *long*, so

```
myMap.get(1)
```

is attempting to look up the key `Integer.valueOf(1)`, whereas

```
myMap.get(getPersonId(..))
```

is looking up the key `Long.valueOf(getPersonId(...))`.  You need to make sure that when you populate the map you are definitely using `Long` keys rather than `Integer` ones, e.g.

```
myMap.put(1L, somePerson)
```

---

In [your original version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29231310/1) you were calling the GORM `get` method on a domain class rather than the `java.util.Map.get` method, and that should work as required as the GORM method call converts the ID to the appropriate type for you before passing it on to Hibernate.

Comment: I resloved my issue but am accepting your answer, it was really fast and clear. Thanks

Comment: But can you help me paraphrase the question title?

Answer (score 1):

I am so sorry the problem was when I initialize the map `myMap`

```
Map<Long, Person> myMap = [1, new Person()]
```

when you say something like this the key is an `integer`but not a `long` still groovy not complaining.

So the problem is my method was returning a long value (`1L`) but my actual key on the map is integer value(`1`).

So changing my map init to  `Map<Long, Person> myMap = [1L, new Person()]` solved the problem.

Probably this due to dynamic nature groovy but irritating unless you know how dynamic langs behave lol.